I am trying to use tuple unpacking for a custom iterable. The iterable size should be increase as the number of variables in the lhs
Write a python class that  gives the expected output Currently gives ValueError
# Can be modified. (Can even be a function or generator
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

#Cannot be modified Cannot pass arguments to MyClass constuctor 
x, y = MyClass()
print(x, y)  # Should return 1, 2 
x, y, z = MyClass() 
print(x, y, z) # 1, 2, 3

Closest workaround is passing argument to the constructor
class MyClass: 
    def init(self, n): 
        self.x = range(n)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(x)

#Cannot be modified I want to avoid passing n
 x, y = MyClass(2)
 x, y, z= MyClass(3) 

Slightly better workaround is to use a very large defualt of n and use * in the end of the lhs
class MyClass: 
    def init(self, n=100): 
        self.x = range(n)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(x)

x, y, *_ = MyClass()
x, y, z, *_ = MyClass() 


Please update the post in include a specific question, or request for help. Also, please proofread the post and address the typos and unclear statements.

"The iterable size should be increase as the number of variables in the lhs" why should it?

print(1, 2, 3) # 1, 2, 3 - That must be a typo, right? You meant print(x, y, z) # 1 2 3?

What's the end goal here? Beware the XY problem; give the context. Maybe what you really want is something like x = next(m); y = next(m) with m some infinite counter.

An iterator can't "query" the assignment to find out how many values will be required. It will produce a fixed number of values, or an indefinite number of values, and one of two things will happen:

The iterator produces exactly as many values as required by the LHS, and the assignment succeeds. (This includes the LHS have a * element, "absorbing" as many values as needed.)
The iterator produces too many or too few values, resulting in a ValueError. (This includes using an infinite iterator, as any finite number of targets will eventually run out.)


An iterator can "query" the assignment to find out how many values will be required.
import traceback

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.end = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        call = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
        self.end = call.line.count(",") + 1
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.count

The traceback is module is used to render source lines in the case of an exception, and assuming the original source lines are available, this introspection approach is possible.
This particular implementation is a proof of concept. Counting the commas is simple and fragile, but it can be made as clever as you want - for example, parsing the caller's code to more reliably determine the form of assignment.
Note that discovering how many items to yield does not always have a unique answer, for example:
first, *middle, last = MyClass()

This form just requires at least 2 items yielded by iterating the right hand side, and "middle" could be a tuple of arbitrary size.
